# Depended types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Can I do the following thing using TypeScript?

There are objects that describe some "action".

```js
export interface IAction {
    action: string;
    data: any;
    otherParam1: number;
    otherParam2: number;
}
```

action is a string and there is a list of possible action ("one", "two", "three" for example).
And the data has different format for each action.

```js
export interface IActionOneData {
    x: number;
}
export interface IActionTwoData {
    y: number;
    z: string;
}
export interface IActionThreeData {
    someList: Array<string>;
}
```

I would like to do something like (if action is "one" then data has "one-format")":

```js
function doAction(action: IAction): void {
    if (action.action === "one") {
        console.log("x = " + action.data.x);
    }
    // ...
}
```

My attempt (don't work):

```js
export enum ActionTypes {
    one = "one",
    two = "two",
}

export interface IAction {
    action: ActionTypes;
    data: any;
    otherParam1: number;
    otherParam2: number;
}

export interface IActionOneData {
    x: number;
}

export interface IActionOne extends IAction {
    action: ActionTypes.one;
    data: IActionOneData;
}

function doAction(action: IAction): void {
    if (action.action === ActionTypes.one) {
        console.log("x = " + action.data.undef); // no error, data is any
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You need to use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) (don't know it's better). Thanks @
captain-yossarian from Ukraine

```js
export enum ActionTypes {
    one = "one",
    two = "two",
}

export interface IActionBase {
    action: ActionTypes;
    data: any;
    otherParam1: number;
    otherParam2: number;
}

export interface IActionOneData {
    x: number;
}
export interface IActionTwoData {
    y: number;
    z: string;
}
export interface IActionThreeData {
    someList: Array<string>;
}

export interface IActionOne extends IActionBase {
    action: ActionTypes.one;
    data: IActionOneData;
}
export interface IActionTwo extends IActionBase {
    action: ActionTypes.two;
    data: IActionTwoData;
}

type IAction = IActionOne | IActionTwo;

function doAction(action: IAction): void {
    if (action.action === ActionTypes.one) {
        console.log("x = " + action.data.x);
    } else if (action.action === ActionTypes.two) {
        console.log("y = " + action.data.y);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you don't know `data` upfront, it worth using `unknown` instead of `any`